# How to expose @EmbeddedId converters in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

There are some Entities with composite Primary Keys and these entities when exposed are having incorrect Links having full qualified name of classes in URL inside _links

Also clicking on links gives such errors -

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type com.core.connection.domains.UserFriendshipId
```

I have XML configured Spring Repository with jpa:repositories enabled and Respository extending from JpaRepository

Can I make Repository implement **org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter** to handle this. Currently getting links as below -

```
_links: {
userByFriendshipId: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/api/userFriendships/com.core.connection.domains.UserFriendshipId@5b10/userByFriendId"
}
```

in xml config , I have jpa:repositories enabled and @RestResource enabled inside Repositories

Comment: I think here solution will be subclassing RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration  and override configureConversionService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first you need to get a usable link. Currently your composite id is exposed as `com.core.connection.domains.UserFriendshipId@5b10`. It should be enough to override the `toString` method of `UserFriendshipId`to produce something useful like `2-3`.

Next you need to implement a [converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert) so that `2-3` can be converted back to a `UserFriendshipId`:

```
class UserFriendShipIdConverter implements Converter<String, UserFriendshipId> {

  UserFriendShipId convert(String id) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Finally you need to register the converter. You already suggested to override `configureConversionService`:

```
protected void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
   conversionService.addConverter(new UserFriendShipIdConverter());
}
```

If you prefer a XML configuration you can follow the instructions in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert-Spring-config).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the accepted answer.. when using spring-boot, in order to get this to work, my class that extends `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` also needed to have the `@Configuration` annotation. I also needed to add the following annotation to my spring boot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(MyConfiguration.class)
public class ApplicationContext {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationContext.class,args);
    }
}
```

I also called the super method within my method that overrides `configureConversionService`:

```
    @Override
    protected void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
        conversionService.addConverter(new TaskPlatformIdConverter());
    }
```

This preserves the default converters, and then adds yours

Comment: A more concise way without needing `configureConversionService()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31830586/122441