# Spring Data Rest @EmbeddedId cannot be constructed from Post Request

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a JPA entity *Person* and an entity *Team*. Both are joined by an entity *PersonToTeam*. This joining entity holds a many-to-one relation to *Person* and one to *Team*. It has a multi-column key consisting of the ids of the *Person* and the *Team*, which is represented by an @EmbeddedId. To convert the embedded id back and forth to the request id I have a converter. All this follows the suggestion on [Spring Data REST @Idclass not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816468/spring-data-rest-idclass-not-recognized)

The code looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class PersonToTeam {
    @EmbeddedId
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private PersonToTeamId id = new PersonToTeamId();

    @ManyToOne
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Team team;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleInTeam role;

    public enum RoleInTeam {
        ADMIN, MEMBER
    }
}

    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @Embeddable
    public class PersonToTeamId implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8450195271351341722L;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Column(name = "person_id")
        private String personId;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Column(name = "team_id")
        private String teamId;
    }

@Component
public class PersonToTeamIdConverter implements BackendIdConverter {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> delimiter) {
        return delimiter.equals(PersonToTeam.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable fromRequestId(String id, Class<?> entityType) {
        if (id != null) {
            PersonToTeamId ptid = new PersonToTeamId();
            String[] idParts = id.split("-");
            ptid.setPersonId(idParts[0]);
            ptid.setTeamId(idParts[1]);
            return ptid;
        }
        return BackendIdConverter.DefaultIdConverter.INSTANCE.fromRequestId(id, entityType);
    }

    @Override
    public String toRequestId(Serializable id, Class<?> entityType) {
        if (id instanceof PersonToTeamId) {
            PersonToTeamId ptid = (PersonToTeamId) id;
            return String.format("%s-%s", ptid.getPersonId(), ptid.getTeamId());
        }
        return BackendIdConverter.DefaultIdConverter.INSTANCE.toRequestId(id, entityType);
    }
}
```

The problem with this converter is, that the fromRequestId method gets a null as id parameter, when a post request tries to create a new personToTeam association. But there is no other information about the payload of the post. So how should an id with foreign keys to the person and the team be created then? And as a more general question: What is the right approach for dealing many-to-many associations in spring data rest?

Comment: why do you have private PersonToTeamId id = new PersonToTeamId();, remove the = new PersonToTeamId(); part and see , that will work.

Comment: This doesn't change a thing. The problem is that the Converter is called with an empty serializable id, when a post is requested.

Comment: Did you find a solution by any chance? I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

After running into the same issue I found a solution. Your code should be fine, except I return `new PersonToTeamId()` instead of the `DefaultIdConverter` if `id` is `null` in `fromRequestId()`.

Assuming you are using JSON in your post request you have to wrap `personId` and `teamId` in an `id` object:

```
{
  "id": {
    "personId": "foo",
    "teamId": "bar"
  },
  ...
}
```

And in cases where a part of the `@EmbeddedId` is not a simple data type but a foreign key:

```
{
  "id": {
    "stringId": "foo",
    "foreignKeyId": "http://localhost:8080/path/to/other/resource/1"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Martin, you save my day!
The detail of "id": {} is very important! @Gregor, mark this answer as correct, please...

Comment: what would be URI for this post request

Comment: @Taimur: What exactly do you want to know? The entity can be exposed at any URI you want it to.

Comment: @Martin I am facing problem with EmbiddedId can you look into this question <br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186824/spring-data-rest-how-to-perform-crud-on-manytomany-relation-composite-table-wi/43230963#43230963