# JpaRepository: findBy not work when entity has composed id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

in my spring boot app I have **entity EntA** and **repository EntARepository**.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(EntAId.class)
public class EntA implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String idA;

  @Id
  private String idB;

  private String name;

  ...
}

public class EntAId implements Serializable {

  private String idA;

  private String idB;
}


public interface RouteRepository  extends JpaRepository<EntA, EntAKey> {

  List<EntA> findByName(String name);

}
```

I had in EntA one id only and everything works, but I added **composed id** recently and I started to get **NPE when calling findByName(String name)** method.

(I still can call save/findOne methods without problem.)

Here is the stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: Did you override `equals()` & `hashcode()` in `EntAId` PK class ?

Comment: Well, I did, but the error is same.

Comment: Did you add default empty constructors? Do you have getters/settery for fields? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816468/spring-data-rest-idclass-not-recognized

Comment: Yes, I have it. I switch back to simple id and I can call findByName without problem.  It seems that there is really issue with composite id.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a typo, but you are referencing a different ID class in your repository declaration from the ID class you have defined:

```
public interface RouteRepository  extends JpaRepository<EntA, EntAKey> 

public class EntAId implements Serializable
```

However, the fact that you can still call `save` and `findOne` suggest that maybe your question has a typo, but your actual code is fine.

Are you sure you are passing a name to `findByName`?  You could place a break point on this method signature to verify...