# Spring Boot JPA RESTful No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type composite key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect my spring boot application to my mysql database. Everything seemed okay until I tried to map an entity with an embeddedId to another entity with another embeddedId.

In my case here, I have a request table and a pledge table. A request can have many pledges.

Request(pid, sttime, extime, endtime, minfund, maxfund, status)

Request id has pid, sttime as composite key.

Pledge(pid, sttime, extime, endtime, minfund, maxfund, status)

Pledge id has four keys, pid, sttime, uemail, and pledgetime, where both pid and sttime references to request.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Request {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RequestId requestId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date extime;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date endtime;
    private int minfund;
    private int maxfund;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private RequestStatus status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pledgeId.request")
    private Collection<Pledge> pledges;

    protected Request(){}

    public Request(RequestId requestId, Date extime, Date endtime, int minfund, int maxfund, RequestStatus status) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.extime = extime;
        this.endtime = endtime;
        this.minfund = minfund;
        this.maxfund = maxfund;
        this.status = status;
    }
    ...
    getters and setters
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Request[pid='%s', sttime='%s', extime='%s', endtime='%s', minfund='%s', maxfund='%s', status='%s']",
                requestId.getProject().getPid(), requestId.getSttime(), extime, endtime, minfund, maxfund, status);
    }
}
```

-

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Date;

@Embeddable
public class RequestId implements Serializable {
//    default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid")
    private Project project;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date sttime;

    protected RequestId(){}

    public RequestId(Project project, Date sttime) {
        this.project = project;
        this.sttime = sttime;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public Date getSttime() {
        return sttime;
    }

    public void setSttime(Date sttime) {
        this.sttime = sttime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        RequestId requestId = (RequestId) o;

        if (project != null ? !project.equals(requestId.project) : requestId.project != null) return false;
        return sttime != null ? sttime.equals(requestId.sttime) : requestId.sttime == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = project != null ? project.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (sttime != null ? sttime.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

//    @Override
//    public String toString() {
//        String timeUrl = "";
//        try {
//            timeUrl = URLEncoder.encode(sttime.toString(), "UTF-8");
//        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//
//        String url = "";
//        try {
//            url = URLEncoder.encode("/search/findRequestByRequestIdProjectAndRequestIdSttime?pid="+project.getPid()+"&sttime="+sttime, "UTF-8");
//        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//
//        return "/search/findRequestByRequestIdProjectPidAndRequestIdSttime?pid="+project.getPid()+"&sttime="+timeUrl;
////        return url;
//    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "/RequestId{" +
                "project=" + project.getPid() +
                ", sttime=" + sttime.toString() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

-

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Pledge {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PledgeId pledgeId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "credit_card")
    private CreditCard credit_card;
    private int amount;

    ...
    constructors
    getter & setters
    ...
}
```

.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Embeddable
public class PledgeId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @MapsId("requestId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "pid"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "sttime")
    })
    private Request request;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "uemail")
    private Customer customer;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date pledgetime;    

    ...
    constructors
    getter & setters
    equals & hashcode
    toString
    ...
}
```

I failed to query every pledges from a certain request.
For example,
http://localhost:8080/requests/RequestId%7Bproject=1,%20sttime=2017-04-16%2012:00:00.0%7D/pledges

> "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [crowdfunding.entity.RequestId]"

Edited: I also tried to override toString() method so that it returns an API that can query itself when exposed, but didn't seem to be working as well.

Comment: I believe the converter that is not found is a REST converter for converting the path parameter (here decoded): `"RequestId{project=1, sttime=2017-04-16 12:00:00.0}"` to an actual `RequestId` object. Search the answer in the REST layer of Spring, not in JPA!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Thank you for your reply. You opened my mind. Could you explained a little bit more to me. I'm still a little confused here. Should I create a converter to parse the inputs?

Comment: [Blockquote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816468/spring-data-rest-idclass-not-recognized/31830586#31830586) Here is the answer!!!