# Spring/jpa tries to get entityEntry from session, but gets null (spring data rest)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-rest

What does it mean, when Spring/jpa tries to get entityEntry object from current session, but gets null.

I said Spring/jpa, because i use Spring Data Rest, but as persistent vendor i use JPA.

org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListever (lines 115 and 116):

```
final EntityEntry entityEntry = source.getPersistenceContext().getEntry( entity );
EntityState entityState = getEntityState( entity, entityName, entityEntry, source );
```

entity object is not null, specifically entity is instance of complex key of class B.

```
@Embeddable
public class BPK implements Serializable
    {

        private Integer idProperty1;
        private Long idProperty2;
        private Integer idProperty3;
        private Integer idProperty4;

        getters/setters...

        hashcode/equals...

    }
```

I try to save class A with PagingAndSortingRepository.

Object to save:

```
{
"id": {
    "idProperty1": 9999,
    "userId": null,
},
"property1": 9,
"property1": 9,
},
"b": [
    {
       "propertyB": 9,
        "id": {
            "idProperty1": 33,
            "idProperty2": 3,
            "idProperty4": 4,
            "idProperty5": 3
        } 
    }
]
}
```

model:

Class A:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "A", schema = "A", catalog = "")
public class A implements Persistable<APK>
{

    private APK id;
    private property1
    private Integer userId;
    private Set<B> b;


    getters/setters...for properties

    equals/hashcode...


    @Valid
    @Size(min = 13,groups = {Required.OnCheck.class})
    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns ({
            @JoinColumn (updatable = false, insertable = false, name = "idProperty1", referencedColumnName = "idProperty1"),
            @JoinColumn (updatable = false, insertable = false, name = "idProperty2", referencedColumnName = "idProperty2")})
    public Set<B> getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Set<B> inB)
    {
        b = inB;
    }

    @Override
    @EmbeddedId
    public APK getId()
    {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(APK aPK)
    {

        this.id = aPK;
    }


    @Override
    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew()
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

class B:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "B", schema = "A", catalog = "")
public class B implements Persistable<BPK>
{
    private BPK id;

    private BigDecimal propertyB;

    getters/setters...for propertyB

    equals/hashcode...

    @Override
    @EmbeddedId
    public B getId()
    {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(BPK id)
    {

        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew()
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

method handleBeforeSave for class A:

```
 @HandleBeforeSave({A.class})
    public void handleBeforeSave(A inInctanceOfClassA)
        {
           final Integer theUserId = itsUserRepository.findUserIdByName("userName");
           inInctanceOfClassA.setUserId(theUserId);
        }
```

User repository inteface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer>, UserRepositoryCustom
{
}
```

Custom user interface:

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom
{
Integer findUserIdByName(final String Name);
}
```

Implementation of user interface:

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom
{
    public Integer findUserIdByName(final String inName)
        {
            Query theQuery = itsEntityManager.createNativeQuery(SQL_FIND_USER_BY_NAME);

            theQuery.setParameter(1, inName);

            final Integer theUserId = (Integer) theQuery.getSingleResult();

            return theUserId;
        }
}
```

When i try to save class A, handleBeforeSave invokes findUserIdByName, this method open new transaction and initiate flash, then spring tries to get state(DELETED,TRANSIENT,DETACHED,PERSISTENT) of object BPK, that's why it tries to get entityEntry object of BPK from current session and gets null, therefore BPK state is TRANSIENT and spring can't finish the save method of class A and i get exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.package.model.B#org.package.model.BPK]
```

So i want to know why `source.getPersistenceContext().getEntry( entity );` returns null

Why it happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, are you sure that your database has data? And second, as far as I know you must define custom converters to get entities with complex keys. [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249506/how-to-expose-embeddedid-converters-in-spring-data-rest) a topic about that. How do you create your BeanPk object?

Comment: I've modified my question, may be it will give to you additional clarification. But my db definitely has appropriate data.

Comment: It seems,you read an `EntityA` from `TransactionA`. And then, you try to read same entity from `TransactionB`. It may be an attribute of some other entity like `EntityB`. Or may be you are trying to clone an Entity over serialisation. This kind of exceptions occurred when the transaction is closed. So it may not be directly about your User, A, B entity or BPK primary key. You must investigate all the operation in your main transaction.