# Spring JPA - mapping foreign keys as a primary key [MySQL]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, entity

I'm having problems in mapping foreign keys as the primary key.

My tables are:

```
client:
PK: id_client

games:
PK: id_game

tickets:
PK: (id_game_fk references game(id_game), id_client_fk references client(id_client))
```

And here are the classes I have defined as entities:

Client.java:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_client")
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Games.java:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "games")
public class Games {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_game")
    private int id;

        public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Ticket.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import Client;
import Games;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3287868602749718327L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TicketId ticketId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_game")
    private Games games;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_client")
    private Client client;

    public TicketId getId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public void setId(TicketId id) {
        this.ticketId = id;
    }

    public Games getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public void setGames(Games games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

TicketId.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class TicketId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6220676431741410239L;

    private int idGameFk;
    private int idClientFk;

    public TicketId(int idGameFk, int idClientFk) {
        this.idGameFk = idGameFk;
        this.idClientFk = idClientFk;
    }

    public int getIdGameFk() {
        return idGameFk;
    }

    public void setIdGameFk(int idGameFk) {
        this.idGameFk = idGameFk;
    }

    public int getIdClientFk() {
        return idClientFk;
    }

    public void setIdClientFk(int idClientFk) {
        this.idClientFk = idClientFk;
    }
}
```

I have tried all the advices I have found so far, but none of them helped. Also, I need this PK to be composed by foreign keys, so I really need help to solve out, how should I map it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @MapsId :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3287868602749718327L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TicketId ticketId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("idGameFk")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_game_fk")
    private Games games;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("idClientFk")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_client_fk")
    private Client client;

    ....
}
```

More info here : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html

Comment: ok, at least it compiles now :D but now I'm getting following exception when calling for the tickets/

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ticket0_.client_id_client' in 'field list'

Comment: Edited answer, could you try what i have added ?

Comment: Can you try to add '@Access(AccessType.FIELD) on the top of your ticket class ?

Comment: Nope, still the same:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ticket0_.client_id_client' in 'field list'

Can't even guess what's the problem..

Comment: here comes a current situation:

'@Entity
'@Table(name = "tickets")
'@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3287868602749718327L;

    '@EmbeddedId
    private TicketId ticketId;

    '@ManyToOne
    '@MapsId("idGameFk")
    private Games games;

    '@ManyToOne
    '@MapsId("idClientFk")
    private Client client;
}

Comment: '@Embeddable
public class TicketId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6220676431741410239L;

    '@Column(name = "id_game_fk")
    private int idGameFk;

    '@Column(name = "id_client_fk")
    private int idClientFk;
}

Anything wrong?

Comment: Nothing seems to be. Can you try the edited answer ? You may have to remove the '@Column s from your TicketId class. I don't currently have access to dev environment so i can't try it out myself.

Comment: A bit different error now:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ticket0_.id_client' in 'field list'
Tried with and without '@Column annotation in the TicketId

Comment: Edited again, sorry, i messed up with the JoinColumns. Tell me the results once you've tried it.

Comment: Ok, awesome, it does returns entries now! However, it doesn't returns game_id and client_id on the call. What have I do to get desired response? Talking about this call:
 http://localhost:8181/tickets/

Comment: Here is an example of response:
"_embedded" : {
    "tickets" : [ {
      "reservationDate" : "2016-08-25",
      "paymentDate" : "2016-08-25",
      "paid" : true,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/tickets/pt.ufutebol.domain.ticket.TicketId@310cc427"
        },
        "game" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/tickets/ticket.TicketId@310cc427/game"
        },
        "client" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/tickets/ticket.TicketId@310cc427/client"
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Reponse from ? Generated REST Services ?

Comment: I'm using crud and spring generate automatically call/responses. For example: my call is: http://localhost:8181/tickets/search/findByPaymentDateBefore?date=2017-01-01 and a response will be all the entries that pass a restriction. There are no manual defenition of queries nor responses :) Everything is automagic :)

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249506/how-to-expose-embeddedid-converters-in-spring-data-rest helps you ?

Comment: Oh nice, I will check it. At least it seems to be what I need :) Thank you very much for your help! If needed, I will create another question ;)