# No converter found capable of converting from type String to type for EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm getting the error below when I try to POST or PUT to my rest resource. The GET and DELETE (for individual `Starlink`s) requests works just fine FWIW. I have other resources which basically follow the same pattern of classes—some with entities with `EmbeddedIds` and some without, and all their REST methods work properly. The only difference is that in this instance, I introduced an entity relationship (`@ManyToOne`) between my `StarLink` class and a `Star` class which allowed me to access my `StarLink`s from a Star resource through HATEOAS—but that seems to have thrown a wrench in things. Tried looking for solutions but, I'm beat.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.beezassistant.configurator.models.StarLinkId]
...
```

Here are the relevant classes:

1. StarLinkRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported=true, path="starlinks")
public interface StarLinkRepository extends JpaRepository<StarLink, StarLinkId> {}
```

2. StarLink.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="starlink")
public class StarLink implements Serializable {
    
    // ...

    @EmbeddedId
    private StarLinkId starLinkId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("starName")
    private Star star;

    private String linkName;
    
    public StarLink() {
        super();
        starLinkId = new StarLinkId();
    }
    
    // Getters and setters
    
}
```

3. StarLinkId

```
@Embeddable
public class StarLinkId implements Serializable {
    
    // ...

    private String starName;
    private String link;
    
    public StarLinkId() {
        super();
    }

    // Getters and setters

    // equals and hashCode
}
```

4. StarLinkIdConverter

```
@Component
public class StarLinkIdConverter implements BackendIdConverter {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> delimiter) {
        return StarLink.class.equals(delimiter);
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable fromRequestId(String id, Class<?> entityType) {
        String[] parts = id.split("__");
        StarLinkId starLinkId = new StarLinkId();
        starLinkId.setStarName(parts[0]);
        try {
            starLinkId.setLink(
                    URLDecoder.decode(
                            parts[1],
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
                    )
            );
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            starLinkId = null;
        }
        return starLinkId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toRequestId(Serializable id, Class<?> entityType) {
        StarLinkId starLinkId = (StarLinkId) id;
        try {
            return String.format(
                    "%s__%s", 
                    starLinkId.getStarName(),
                    URLEncoder.encode(
                            starLinkId.getLink(), 
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
                    )
            );
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Just a note that it's considered a bad practice to tie your domain model (if you JPA entities happen to be your domain model) to your API. I would suggest you to create classes that represent the resources so each can evolve independetly.

Comment: @Augusto Hmmm, that's new. To the extent that my code reflects that flaw would mostly have to do with the fact that the tutorials I've been using as a guide seem to follow the same pattern. Do you have any resources I can refer to on that particular topic?

Comment: I would guess you've been following Spring tutorials: those try to make a point in the least amount of code using as much voodoo as possible (a marketing gimmick). I think all books on design specifically mention to not tie the domain with the API to allow both to evolve independently. A typical approach to this is Ports and Adapters (also called Hexagonal Architecture, Onion Architecture or Clean Architecture). I would recommend you to get a copy of `Implementing Domain-Driven Design`, but again most books about design talk about the importance of this separation.

Comment: I run out of space above. Most 'tutorials' online are about sharing something cool, not exactly sharing something good. My favourite example is this blog post: https://dzone.com/articles/an-alternative-approach-to-threadlocal-using-sprin-1 - The author suggest to replace a single `ThreadLocal` variable for a bunch of Spring voodoo that most people don't understand... but hey, it's cool! I'm not trying to be flippant, I've done enough damage doing 'cool' stuff in my career, so please ask away any other questions! I'm happy to suggest more books or other resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I found a related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249506/how-to-expose-embeddedid-converters-in-spring-data-rest).
Implementing a `BackendIdConverter` will not work as it's for Spring WebMVC controllers.

You need to implement a `Converter<String, StarLinkId>`, as follows:

```
public class StarLinkIdConverter implements Converter<String, StarLinkId> {

    @Override
    public StarLinkId convert(String source) {
        String[] parts = source.split("__");
        StarLinkId starLinkId = new StarLinkId();
        starLinkId.setStarName(parts[0]);
        try {
            starLinkId.setLink(
                    URLDecoder.decode(
                            parts[1],
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
                    )
            );
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            starLinkId = null;
        }
        return starLinkId;
    }
    
}
```

Then you have to register this converter in your configuration, in your class where you extend `RepositoryRestConfigurer`, as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
        conversionService.addConverter(new StarLinkIdConverter());
    }
```

This will give you the conversion from the request URI to your `StarLinkId`, and this will make requests work as long as you assemble the request URI yourself, but to correctly do HATEOAS you still need to make sure you return the correctly formatted URIs, by overriding `toString` in your `StarLinkId` class:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            return String.format(
                    "%s__%s", 
                    getStarName(),
                    URLEncoder.encode(
                            getLink(), 
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
                    )
            );
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested the above code, but these steps fixed this issue for me.

Comment: It could be that you don't need to URL decode the string you get in `source`, I imagine this has already been decoded

Comment: This was an integral part of reaching the final solution in my case. Had a few things I had to subsequently iron out, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The `BackendIdConverter` did get the job done hitherto as far as dealing with entities without children entities